# Add numbers from a list to an existing file using python

Tags: python

I have a text file with say 14 lines, and I would like to add list items from a list to the end of each of these lines, starting with the 5th line. Can anyone help me out please. 
e.g
I have this text file called `test.txt`:

```
a b
12
1
four
/users/path/apple 
/users/path/banana 
..
..
```

and I have the  following list

cycle=[21,22,23,.....]

My question is how can add these list items to the end of the lines such that I get this:

```
a b
12
1
four
/users/path/apple 21
/users/path/banana 22
..
..
```

I am not very good at python and this seems like a simple problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you know whether you should add to a line or not? Slashes?

Comment: Could you show some code of what you have tried so far?

Comment: I don't want to add the list items in the first 4 lines. so far I have tried and the list items are added as new lines which I do not want.

Comment: Why dont you do the seek if you know which position you have to add the content. To seek you can use linecache module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you cannot modify a file except to append things at the end of the file (after the last line).

In your case, you want to:

1. Read the file, lines by lines
2. Append something to the line (optionally)
3. Write that line back.

You can do it in several ways. Load -> Write back modified string would be the simplest:

```
with open("path/to/my/file/test.txt", 'rb') as f:
    # Strip will remove the newlines, spaces, etc...
    lines = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]
numbers = [21, 22, 23]
itr = iter(numbers)
with open("path/to/my/file/test.txt", 'wb') as f:
    for line in lines:
        if '/' in line:
            f.write('%s %s\n' % (line, itr.next()))
        else:
            f.write('%s\n' % line)
```

The issue with this method is that if you do a mistake with your processing, you ruined the original file. Other methods would be to:

- Do all the modifications on the list of lines, check, and write back the whole list
- Write back into a newly created file, possibly renaming it in the end.

As always, the [Python doc](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) is a definitely good read to discover new features and patterns.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
for line in file.readlines():
    print line.rstrip(), cycle.pop(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cycle = [21, 22, 23]
i = 0
with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as fh:
    with open('new_myfile.txt', 'w' as fh_new:
        for line in fh:
            addon = ''
            if i < len(cycle):
                addon = cycle[i]
            fh_new.write(line.strip() + addon + '\n')
            i += 1
```